No search to add intellij gradient dependencies

Hello,
I am using Gradle for Spring Boot development in IntelliJ. I tried to add a dependency by navigating to "Add dependency" in the build.gradle file.
However, when I search there, it does not show search results as expected, and only displays the items that are already installed.
How can I resolve this issue?
Search to add Dependency, but it doesn't work

Could you please clarify what action did you use?
